# deploying Qt/QML App with LocalStorage (Sqlite) on OS X

Tags: qt, sqlite, qml

I'm doing an app with QML that uses LocalStorage to store some informations.
It's working fine when I run in debug mode.

My `storage.js` that access the database is like that.

```
.import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0 as Sql

// First, let's create a short helper function to get the database connection
function getDatabase() {
     return Sql.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("MyApp", "0.1", "StorageDatabase", 100000);
}
```

My Qt `.pro` file contains the Sql module:

```
QT += sql
```

And at first moment it runs fine in Release mode either.

But when I try to deploy on OSX, running `macdeployqt` like that:

```
macdeployqt MyApp.app -dmg -qmldir=../MyApp/qml/
```

First I got one error, but I think that's ok because I don't use MySQL: ERROR: no file at

```
"/opt/local/lib/mysql55/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib"
```

I'm using sqlite via LocalStorage.

Then trying to run in Release mode it doesn't work anymore, the database access doesn't work, not even the in the deployment it works... now when I try to run the app I got the error:

```
storage.js:5: ReferenceError: Sql is not defined
```

The `line 5` is this one:

```
return Sql.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("MyApp", "0.1", "StorageDatabase", 100000);
```

And the Sql name is defined in the first line:

```
.import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0 as Sql
```

Looking for this error in the internet I found some places telling to do exactly what I did, like here: https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/28371

Any clue about this?

I'm using **Qt5.2, Quick 2.0, Qt Creator 3.01**

Comment: I may say something trivial, but can you check that `.import` method worked correctly and `Sql`object initiated properly? Add some code for that and do deployment. Have you got MySQL as a pert of you development kit?

Comment: Well, it seems so, it works fine in debug mode, that should indicate that the import is fine, right?

I don't have MySQL, I'm using Sqlite as the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to this Qt bug that is here since Qt5.1
https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29805/

I've used the script and custom macdeployqt linked in the post to make this work.

Script: https://gist.github.com/lasconic/5965542
Custom macdeployqt: https://github.com/MaximAlien/macdeployqt

It seems that Qt is not giving much attention to desktop development, only that explains a bug like that not fixed yet.